# Ionic Android RuntimeException FirebaseInitProvider IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

Project build using Ionic. After generating Android build and import in Android SDK.

It gives error while running app in device/simulator. Also using FCM for push notifications.

Android runtime error after installing APK:

```
--------- beginning of crash

2018-05-04 16:34:30.077 14810-14810/com.app.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.name, PID: 14810
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcq.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzj.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzo.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer$$CC.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzg.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Is there a problem with my configuration or is something missing while processing Android build?

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue and solved that problem now.
In my case, empty, or null value is "current_key" value in `google-services.json`so I fill the value (web API key) found in the Firebase console